# Override mirage response in Acceptance tests?

Tags: ember.js, overriding, acceptance-testing, ember-cli-mirage

In our Ember app [v.2.14], we're using mirage to mock our APIs and have provided the direct response for our model 'car'

mirage/config.js:

```
 this.get('/cars', () => {
 return {
  "data": {
    "type": "car",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
     "exists" : true
    }
   }
 }
```

In our acceptance tests, I want to override this. 
I understand that using factories and fixtures we can feed the mirage store which *CAN* be overridden in the tests using `server.create()`. 
It doesn't work though when I am providing the direct response as above. Any clues if it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. You’d need to use `server.get()` in your acceptance test, but things should work fine.

If you still have trouble, if you post your code that isn’t working in your test we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

yes. in the test file mock will override config one inside the test make sure endpoint are exactly the same.